# Lambda parameter typing syntactic sugar?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can I "destructure" the type for the props of a functional component?

This compiles fine.

```
type DataType = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
};

const ShowA = ({ a }: DataType) => <p>{a}</p>;
```

However, this does not:

```
const Component = () => {
  const data = { a: "foo", b: "bar" };
  <ShowA a={data.a} />;
};
```

Which causes the error `Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: string; }' but required in type 'DataType'.`.

I understand the error but is there syntax I can use to allow this?
`b` will always be in the retrieved data so it feels wrong to mark it as optional `b?: string`. My hope is that there's a one-line alternative to this:

```
const ShowA = (props: DataType) => {
  const { a } = props;
  return <p>{a}</p>;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript has an utility type that does exactly that: [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)

```
type DataType = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
};

type OnlyAType = Pick<DataType, "a"> // { a: string }

const ShowA = ({ a }: Pick<DataType, "a">) => <p>{a}</p>;
```

Comment: You missed the ">" in the function parameter type :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, not my edit, but all should be good now :)